# Will_paginate for includes comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, will-paginate

I'm discovering the gem will_paginate which is great ! But I'm facing a problem of using. I'm building a group>post>comments app, so in my group show page i'm displaying posts and their comments. To limit the numbers of queries, i'm using includes method like this :

Group_controller :

```
  def show
    @posts = @group.posts.order(upd_at: :desc).includes(:user).includes(comments: :user).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

So I would like to also paginate my comments. Do you know a way to do that ?

My code :
Group_show =

```
<h1>Groupe <%= @group.name %></h1>
<div class="post_list<%=@group.id%>">
  <%= render @posts %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

And my posts/_post =

```
<% @comments = post.comments %>
<ul id="comment_list<%=post.id%>">
  <%- if @comments.any? %>
    <%= render @comments, post: post %>
    <%= will_paginate @comments, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

By the way if you have a method to define @comments directly in the Groups_controller(show), it can be really useful ;)

Comment: I wonder if it makes more sense to simply limit your `post.comments` to the most recent (3): `post.comments.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)`. Then have a button that performs an ajax request to another endpoint that will render the remaining requests if they're desired by the user... I would think that would be more efficient.

Comment: @BigRon, thanks for your answer, I already order this like that into my model comment. Can you show how can look like an ajax request to perform that ?

Comment: Try `@posts = Post.where(group_id: @group.id).order(upd_at: desc).includes(:user, { comments: :user })`

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% tested, but I think this should work. Do you know how all these components work? If not, let me know and I can explain.

**posts/_post**

```
<% @comments = post.comments.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3) %>
<ul id="comment_list<%=post.id%>">
  <%- if @comments.any? %>
    <%= render @comments, post: post %>
    <%- if post.comments.offset(3).exists? # this is more efficient than count > 3 bc it quits counting after 3 %>
      <!-- the below link_to creates: href="/posts/:id/comments" ... -->
      <!-- ... and `remote: true` makes that an ajax request -->
      <li><%= link_to "more", comments_post_path(post), class: "more-comments-btn", remote: true %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

</ul>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
  # `member do` is explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions
  member do
    get :comments
  end
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
# GET /posts/:id/comments
def comments
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments.order(created_at: :desc)
  # since you requested this url via ajax with `remote: true` rails will automatically render `posts/comments.js.erb` ...
  # ... rather than a typical html request where rails would automatically render `posts/comments.html.erb`
end
```

**views/posts/comments.js.erb**

```
// some people like to use render @comments as shorthand like you did above. I'm a fan of being more explicit like the below
$("#comment_list<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/comments', locals: {comments: @comments, post: @post}) %>");
// now remove the more comments button
$("#comment_list<%= @post.id %>").find(".more-comments-btn").remove();
```

The documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements) explains the use of `remote: true` for ajax requests. Scroll down to section "3.1.2 link_to" and then section 5.1 for the controller and js.erb view.

Comment: thanks you so much @BigRon for your explanation on this topic. The way to achieve it looks much more clear now. I still have some errors but I can work solve that by myself. Thanks again, good continuation on your stuffs