# Paginate an include variable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm building an app which have group > posts > comments
To reduce the number of SQL requests, i'm using the includes method

```
# group controller
def show
  @posts = @group.posts.includes(:comments)
end
```

Now, I would like to paginate comments. But I don't know how to use the function .paginate from the gem will_paginate

Do you have a tips for that ?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous [Will_paginate for includes comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45240450/477037)? I'm inclined to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it's not exacltly the same request, the first one was to send a ajax request to load more comments, but I'm not using the function .paginate. And It can be usefull to have access to this function.

Comment: Can u elaborate with respect to view?

Comment: 3 people favourited this question in 15 minutes?

Comment: @krishnar, what do you mean ? I don't really understand your comment

Comment: I mean how your pagination should work? For every post , paginated comments? Explain

Comment: @krishnar, yep exactly ! Every list of comments (one by post) will be paginated

Comment: Simple suggestion.. 1. Load all post within group 2.whenver user says show comments for specific post just do paginate for that post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue with pagination inside controller**

Since you want paginated comments associated with individual post, it's complicate to achieve in controller as you need to create N paginated comment object (say you have N posts).

**What you can do**

1.load posts as usual with included comments to reduce excess queries. But don't run paginate here

2.achieve pagination inside view only

```
<%= @posts.each do | post | %>
<% comments = post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>

..
...
...
<%= will_paginate comments%>
<% end %>
```